# How can I get a list of plugins and which blogs are using them?

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin, sql

I'm about to upgrade my Wordpress MU installation to wordpress 3

Before I update, I want to find out which blogs use which plugins.

I don't see a way to do that in the UI, is there?

What about a query of the mysql database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [Plugin Commander](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-commander/) which is a plugin management plugin for multi-site mode, which allows further control on network-activated plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with `Plugin Commander` with version `3.4.1` but [WPMU Plugin Stats](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmu-plugin-stats/installation/) seems to be working pretty well even though it has not been updated in 2 years.